# Modifying template according to date with django

Tags: python, django

I'm wanting to modify the options on a template according to the date.

The code I'm suspecting will look something like this:

```
{% for campaign in filter.qs %}
{% if campaign.event_date__gte=datetime.today() %}
<code> 
{% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

I believe my issue is that I'm trying to write it like a view - I'm just not too sure how to edit this within the template and not the views.py

Answer (score 1):

i think sample solution for is to create model `property`

```
class YOUMODEL():

    @property
    def is_today_or_after(self):
        return self.event_date > datetime.today()
```

and then use in the template:

```
{% for campaign in filter.qs %}
{% if campaign.is_today_or_after %}
<code> 
{% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with a **property method** by adding it to your model class.

```
import datetime 
today = datetime.datetime.today()
```

```
class ModelClass(models.Model):
    # fields 
    @property
    def is_future_date(self):
        return self.event_date >= today
```

---

```
{% for campaign in filter.qs %}
     {% if campaign.is_future_date %}
          # <code> 
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But in case you have multiple different `date`s that require comparison, or you want to know whether it's a past, present future `date`, writing a property method for each model is **NOT THE BEST ONE**. So instead of property method, I would suggest writing a **tag filter**, then import it to your template, so you will be able to compare `date`s wherever in your template for whatever instance.

Here an example:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
import datetime

@register.filter
def is_future_date(date):
    return date >= datetime.datetime.today()
```

To use it in your template, call it that way

```
{% for campaign in filter.qs %}
     {% if campaign.event_date|is_future_date %}
          <code> 
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another `date` in your template:

```
{% if another_instance.date|is_future_date %}
     # I am able to do it with whatever model
     # no need to create multiple property methods
{% endif %}
```